# how to set position of image to center in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing site in which,I want to show image on slider but as I have give `height` of `div` in 500 only some part of image is displaying
 **i.e** from top to bottom.I want image should be of same height but it should get displayed from center

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="../armando-master/assets/img/Relax.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" 
        style="width:100%;" "height: 50%">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/img/blog/1.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;" 
       "height: 50%">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/img/blog/3.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;" 
        "height: 50%">`enter code here`
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please attach a screenshot of how it's appearing now.

Comment: try to use `background-image` in `.item` class instead of `img` with `background-position:center center`

Comment: There is some syntax error in `style="width:100%;" "height: 50%"` it should be `style="width:100%;height: 50%;"`

Answer (score 0):

`<img style="width: 100%; height:100%; object-fit: cover;" />` should do the trick.